# Subversion SVN: Continuous Integration with Post-Commit Hooks?

Tags: svn, hook

I'm using CentOS, Apache, PHP, MySQL and Subversion. I would like to update my deployment code everytime a user commits new code. Can I do that with a SVN Post-Commit Hook? What would the hook look like?

My repository is under: /var/svn/repository, and my deployment folder is on the same machine under /var/www/myWebAppTest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to make `/var/www/myWebAppTest` a subversion checkout. Then, the post-commit hook could read

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/myWebAppTest
svn up
```

You may have to restart Apache also, if so, add `apache2ctl graceful` at the end of the script.

Comment: I used svn export to get all files from my repository into the specific folder, so that in doesnt contain these .svn folders that I dont need. Do I need to make this folder a real working copy to make your code work?

Comment: I get: 'post-commit' failed with error output:
So, there is no error output. How can I at least get any error output?

Comment: Yes, you need a regular checkout to make "svn up" work, and you do need the .svn folders for that. If you absolutely don't want them, do "svn export" on every commit, first deleting the old tree. To get the error output, redirect it into a file, and inspect that file.